# data packet switch problems on network

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, network-protocols

A question about computer networking.

Suppose on a packet switch network, a data sender send data much faster than the speed of receiving data on the data receiver ?

What are the reasons ? And, how to solve the problem ?

My idea: there are congestion on the route between the sender and receiver.

Another question:

How to verify the link between two nodes have a problem ? such as a broken link ? 
My idea: use tcproute to do the test

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Suppose on a packet switch network, a data sender send data much faster than the speed of receiving data on the data receiver.

What are the reasons?

*One reason could be that the receiver has less bandwidth than the sender*

how to solve the problem ?

*if TCP is used, TCP's congestion control mechanism will solve this problem (the sender will adapt its sending rate to the bottleneck of the complete path to the receiver)*

How to verify the link between two nodes have a problem ? such as a broken link ?

*You can use **ping** or **traceroute** to check if there is a route between two hosts*

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose on a packet switch network, a data sender send data much
>   faster than the speed of receiving data on the data receiver ?
>
> What are the reasons ? And, how to solve the problem ?
>
> My idea: there are congestion on the route between the sender and
>   receiver.

Differences in processing speed of both ends.
Solve: see TCP "window"

> Another question:
>
> How to verify the link between two nodes have a problem ? such as a
>   broken link ? My idea: use tcproute to do the test

Use ping or traceroute for details.